# VueJs & Vuex | get data from store from a component after mutation from another component

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have two vuejs components, one that will mutate the store, and another that will need to retrieve that new data from the store. I know how to get that new data using store.getters, but I'm not sure how that to access that new data in the first place from the component that is getting that data.

Which vuejs component method do I use to be able to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add your store and 2 components code?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use a computed property.

Let's say that the data is an array and you have components A and B.

- The data isn't available in the beginning
- B returns an empty array through the computed property
- A updates the store with the data
- B automatically now returns an array with the data through the computed property

When the data isn't available you can either have an empty array in its place (literally just []) or if it's not that easy, you'll have to write some logic to the computed property so that it can decide if the data is available or not and either return it or an empty array.

If you only use the data in B you might not need a getter, you could write all the logic in B's computed property. But that's an opinion.

Remember to take Vue's reactivity system into account and update the array in a correct way. Otherwise the components won't get updated with new data.